# Checking for nulls with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I can never seem to get the filter calls right when I want to check for null values.

Is this function unnecessary?

```
def sqla_false(field):
    if field.type.__class__ == db.String:
        return db.or_(field == None, field == '')
    return field == None
```

How does sqlalchemy store unset fields? 
What if one of my wtforms forms sends a "" as a value for one of the fields, would NULL or "" be stored in the database when I call form.populate_obj(obj)?

Answer (score 1):

If you send `''`, then that is stored and read as the empty string.  If you send `None`, then that is stored as `NULL` and read as `None`.  Use `isinstance(field, db.String)` to check for type.  Use `db.and_(field.isnot(None), field != '')` to check that it has a non-empty string value.